# PHP preg_replace with SQL

Tags: php, mysql, preg-replace

I'm trying to replace a simple command from a basic CMS with a database call.

The user enters

```
[gallery id=x]
```

into the CMS, and I want this to go away, find the images included in that gallery, and display them (ready for the jQuery Cycle plugin)

I can get:

```
$pattern = '/\[gallery id=(\w+)\]/i';
$rpl     = 'Display Gallery ID ${1}';
$bubble  = preg_replace($pattern, $rpl, $bubble);
```

...which returns "Display Gallery 12" (for example). However I need it to do this:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM galleries INNER JOIN photos ON photos.PhotoGallery=galleries.GalleryID WHERE GalleryID='x'";
$set = mysql_query($sql);
echo '<div id="gallery">';
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($set))
{
 echo '<img src="'.$row['PhotoPath'].'" />';
}
echo '</div>';
```

Comment: The `mysql_*` functions will be [deprecated in PHP 5.5](http://php.net/manual/en/faq.databases.php#faq.databases.mysql.deprecated). It is not recommended for writing new code as it will be removed in the future. Instead, either the [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) and [be a better PHP Developer](http://jason.pureconcepts.net/2012/08/better-php-developer/).

Comment: With that said, elaborate on *something like this*.

Comment: Are you just asking how to match and return the value rather than replace it?  See [preg_match](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php).

Comment: I can't figure out what he's asking for. How does the query at the bottom relate to the substitution at the top? Is the question about how to get the value of x to substitute into the SQL?

Comment: @JasonMcCreary - Changed to read "need to do this". The ID number in the [gallery id=XXX] command needs to be carried through to an SQL statement (SELECT WHERE id=XXX)

Comment: @ficuscr - No, I need the ID number to be passed to the SQL statement.

Comment: @Barmar - Yes, exactly. [gallery id=XXX] needs to be replaced with an SQL statement "SELECT WHERE id=XXX" and echo out the results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `preg_replace_callback` function, which takes each match your regular expression finds and replaces it with the string returned from a provided callback.  So you could do something like:

```
function generateGallery($matches) {
    // generate the string here, $matches[1] will be your gallery id
    return "Gallery Content for Gallery " . $matches[1];
}

$pattern = '/\[gallery id=(\w+)\]/i';
$bubble = preg_replace_callback($pattern, generateGallery, $bubble);
```

Comment: What does this do that you can't do with an ordinary `preg_replace()`?

Comment: He wanted to execute SQL statements based in the id number in the matched tag and generate the replacement that way.  The `generateGallery` callback gives him a convenient place to do that once the id is known.

Comment: But not a convenient way to echo the results of the query into the page, unless they happen to be part of the replacement.

Comment: He was using echo in his example, but what he was echoing was the replacement string.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
preg_match($pattern, $string, $matches);
```

After this, the ID is in `$matches[1]`.